# How to efficiently find moments of a multinormal distribution?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, probability-or-statistics

**Update:** Starting from V10.0 the build-in `Moment` is fast enough for practical use.

---

I have a multinormal distribution with covariance matrix $\sigma$ and zero mean. I want to find moment

$$
E[x_1^{r_1}x_2^{r_2}\cdots x_n^{r_n}] =\,?
$$

Of course, there is a built-in function [`Moment`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Moment.html), but it is quite slow for big moments

```
Moment[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{σ[1, 1], σ[1, 2]}, {σ[2, 1], σ[2, 2]}}], 
  {20, 20}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 1.604658

*Is there a more efficient method?* It is related to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6845/4678) and my answer there.

I think that [Isserlis' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis'_theorem) is helpful. It says

$$
E[x_1x_2\cdots x_n] = \sum\prod E[x_ix_j]
$$
if $n$ even and $0$ if $n$ odd, by definition $E[x_ix_j]=\sigma_{ij}$. Here the notation $\sum\prod$ means summing over all distinct ways of partitioning $x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n$ into unordered pairs.

For example, $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ can be spitted as
$$
(x_1,x_2),(x_3,x_4);\quad (x_1,x_3),(x_2,x_4);\quad (x_1,x_4),(x_2,x_3).
$$
Therefore,

$$
E[x_1x_2x_3x_4]=\sigma _{1,2} \sigma _{3,4}+\sigma _{1,3} \sigma _{2,4}+\sigma _{1,4} \sigma _{2,3}.
$$

If we want to calculate $E[x_1^2x_2x_3]$ then we can put two indexes equal (e.g. $x_4=x_2$) in the previous equation

$$
E[x_1^2x_2x_3] = \sigma _{1,1} \sigma _{2,3} + 2 \sigma _{1,2} \sigma _{1,3}.
$$

Another examples:

$$
E[x_1^2x_2^2] = \sigma _{1,1} \sigma _{2,2} + 2 \sigma _{1,2}^2,
$$

$$
E[x_1^3x_2] = 3 \sigma _{1,1} \sigma _{1,2},
$$

$$
E[x_1^4] = 3 \sigma _{1,1}^2.
$$

For six variables there is 15 terms:

$$
E[x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5x_6]=\sigma _{1,2} \sigma _{3,4} \sigma _{5,6}+\sigma _{1,2} \sigma _{3,5} \sigma _{4,6}+\sigma _{1,2} \sigma _{3,6} \sigma
   _{4,5}+\sigma _{1,4} \sigma _{2,5} \sigma _{3,6}+\sigma _{1,5} \sigma _{2,4} \sigma _{3,6}+\sigma _{1,4} \sigma _{2,6} \sigma
   _{3,5}+\sigma _{1,6} \sigma _{2,4} \sigma _{3,5}+\sigma _{1,5} \sigma _{2,6} \sigma _{3,4}+\sigma _{1,6} \sigma _{2,5} \sigma
   _{3,4}+\sigma _{1,3} \sigma _{2,4} \sigma _{5,6}+\sigma _{1,4} \sigma _{2,3} \sigma _{5,6}+\sigma _{1,3} \sigma _{2,5} \sigma
   _{4,6}+\sigma _{1,5} \sigma _{2,3} \sigma _{4,6}+\sigma _{1,3} \sigma _{2,6} \sigma _{4,5}+\sigma _{1,6} \sigma _{2,3} \sigma
   _{4,5}.
$$

As you can see, this statistical problem is just a combinatorics problem: find all possibilities to put $r_1$ balls of type $1$, $r_2$ balls of type $2$, ..., and $r_n$ balls of type $n$ to bins. Each bin can take 2 and only 2 balls.

Comment: In *Mathematica* version 10.3 on Mac OS X, I get a much better timing for the moments. Your example yields `AbsoluteTiming` of `0.004` here. It looks like some serious improvements have happened in the new version. This apparently makes my answer to [How to deal with complicated gaussian integrals in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6846/245) roughly as fast as yours now...

Comment: @Jens Thank you, it is a good news!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Explicit formula

The wolfies' answer gave me an idea that one can derive an explicit formula. Here it is!

$$
E(x_1^{r_1}x_2^{r_2}\cdots x_n^{r_n}) = \sum_{(p)}\prod_{i}\frac{r_i!\,\sigma_{ii}^{p_{ii}}}{(2p_{ii})!!}\prod_{i<j}\frac{\sigma_{ij}^{p_{ij}}}{p_{ij}!}
$$

where sum is performed over all non-negative integer values of $p_{ii}$ and $p_{ij}$ with constrain

$$
\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}p_{ji}+2p_{ii}+\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}p_{ij}=r_i, \quad i=1,2,\ldots,n.
$$

### Implementation

```
moment2[x_List] := With[{n = Length[x]}, 
  With[{σii = Table[σ[i, i], {i, n}], σij = Join @@ Table[σ[i, j], {i, n}, {j, i + 1, n}],
    pij = Table[Unique[], {n (n - 1)/2}], 
    pos = n (n - 1)/2 - (n - Min[##] + 1) (n - Min[##])/2 + Abs[# - #2] &},
   With[{pii = Table[x[[i]] - Sum[If[i == j, 0, pij[[pos[i, j]]]], {j, n}], {i, n}]/2, 
     lim = Sequence @@ Join @@ Table[{pij[[pos[i, j]]], 
       x[[i]] - Sum[If[i == k, 0, pij[[pos[i, k]]]], {k, j - 1}], 
       0, -If[j == n, 2, 1]}, {i, n}, {j, i + 1, n}]},
    With[{arg = Times @@ ((x! σii^pii)/(2 pii)!!) Times @@ (σij^pij/pij!)},
      If[Length[{lim}] == 0, arg, Sum[arg, lim]]]]]]

moment2[{19, 20, 21}] // Hash // AbsoluteTiming
moment[{19, 20, 21}] // Hash // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.036750, 4700900427412246901}
>
> {2.762643, 4700900427412246901}

It is very fast and requred no memory for memoization (for large moments `moment`  takes a huge amount of memory). The leaf count is small as in the wolfies' answer.

### Derivation of the formula

#### One variable

At the beginning, let us consider the simplest case with one variable $E(x_1^{r_1})$. The moment generation function is

$$
m(t_1) = \exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{11}t_1^2\right).
$$

The first derivatives are

$$
\frac{\partial m}{\partial t_1}(t_1) = t_1 \sigma_{11}\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{11}t_1^2\right),
$$

$$
\frac{\partial^2 m}{\partial t_1^2}(t_1) = (t_1^2 \sigma_{11}^2+\sigma_{11})\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{11}t_1^2\right),
$$

$$
\frac{\partial^3 m}{\partial t_1^3}(t_1) = (t_1^3 \sigma_{11}^3+3t_1\sigma_{11}^2)\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{11}t_1^2\right),
$$

$$
\frac{\partial^4 m}{\partial t_1^4}(t_1) = (t_1^4 \sigma_{11}^4+6t_1^2\sigma_{11}^3+3\sigma_{11}^2)\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{11}t_1^2\right)
$$

and so on. Then to calculate the moment we need to put $t_1=0$. For the forth moment we have

$$
\frac{\partial^4 m}{\partial t_1^4}(0) = 3\sigma_{11}^2.
$$

This process can be represented by the following scheme

[image]

We can take the derivative of:

1. The exponent. It increases the power of $t_{1}$ by 1 and multiply by $\sigma_{11}$. It is represented by the upward arrows (all of them has multiplication factor $\sigma_{11}$).
2. The pre-exponential polynomial. It decreases the power of $t_1$ by 1 and multiply by the current power of $t_1$. It is represented by the downward arrows (their multiplication factors correspond to the vertical position).

At the end we need to come to the zero vertical position. All other terms disappear after substitution $t_1=0$. To obtain the moment we need to sum  products of factors of all possible paths.

Example for $r_1=10$:

[image]

One can check that we obtain the known result

$$
E(x_1^{r_1}) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
(r_1-1)!!\sigma_{11}^{r_1/2} & \text{if }r_1\text{ is even},\\
0 & \text{if }r_1\text{ is odd}.
\end{array}\right.
$$

For the odd $r_1$ there is simply no paths.

#### Two variables

With two variables the moment generating function is

$$
m(t_1,t_2) = \exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{11}t_1^2+\frac{1}{2}\sigma_{22}t_2^2+\sigma_{12}t_1t_2\right).
$$

The moment $E(x_1^{r_1}x_2^{r_2})$ can be calculated with

$$
E(x_1^{r_1}x_2^{r_2}) = \frac{\partial^{r_1+r_2} m}{\partial t_1^{r_1}\partial t_2^{r_2}}\Bigg|_{\substack{t_1=0,\\t_2=0}}
$$

For definiteness we will:

$~~\rm A.$ take all derivatives with respect to $t_1$,

$~~\rm B.$ then take all derivatives with respect to $t_2$.

At the stage $\rm A$ there are three possibilities:

1. Increase the power of $t_{1}$ by 1 and multiply by $\sigma_{11}$.
2. Increase the power of $t_{2}$ by 1 and multiply by $\sigma_{12}$.
3. Decrease the power of $t_1$ by 1 and multiply by the current power of $t_1$.

After the stage $\rm A$ we substitute $t_1=0$.

At the stage $\rm B$ there are only to possibilities:

1. Increase the power of $t_{2}$ by 1 and multiply by $\sigma_{22}$.
2. Decrease the power of $t_2$ by 1 and multiply by the current power of $t_2$.

We don't consider production of powers of $t_1$ because they will be killed at the final substitution $t_1=0,t_2=0$.

Let us consider $E(x_1^6x_2^4)$. If at the stage $\rm A$ we always choose cases 1 or 3 (not 2) then it can be represented as multiplication of two full diagrams

[image]

If at the stage $\rm A$ we choose case 2 two times then it can be represented as multiplication of the diagrams

[image]

The first diagram is smaller by 2 because we consume 2 of 6 derivatives with respect to $t_1$ to produce $t_2$. The binomial coefficient $\binom{6}{2}$ is the number of possible choices of the case 2. The second diagram starts from the position 2 because we produce $t_2^2$ at the stage $\rm A$.

One can show that the sum of the diagram with $r_2$ derivatives and the initial position $k_2$ is
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{r_2!}{(r_2-k_2)!!}\sigma_{22}^{(r_2-k_2)/2} & \text{if }r_2-k_2\text{ is even},\\
0 & \text{if }r_2-k_2\text{ is odd}.
\end{array}\right.
$$

Therefore, the term $\sigma_{11}^{p_{11}}\sigma_{12}^{p_{12}}\sigma_{22}^{p_{22}}$ in the moment $E(x_1^{r_1}x_2^{r_2})$ has the coefficient

$$
\frac{(2p_{11})!}{(2p_{11})!!}\frac{r_1!}{(p_{12})!(r_1-p_{12})!}\frac{r_2!}{(r_2-p_{12})!!} =\\
\frac{r_1!}{(2p_{11})!!}\frac{1}{p_{12}!}\frac{r_2!}{(2p_{22})!!}
$$

where I use that $2p_{11}+p_{12}=r_1$ and $p_{12}+2p_{22}=r_2$. This formula tell us the form of the general formula which I wrote in the beginning. One can check that the formula has the same form for any number of variables. I didn't write it here because it is much more complicated. I just give an example for diagrams in the case of three variables.

#### Three variables

Let us consider $E(x_1^7x_2^6x_3^5)$ and coefficient before $\sigma_{11}^2\sigma_{12}^\vphantom{2}\sigma_{13}^2\sigma_{22}^2\sigma_{23}^\vphantom{2}\sigma_{33}^\vphantom{2}$.

[image]

[image]

The coefficient is

```
4!/4!! Multinomial[1, 2, 4] 5!/4!! Multinomial[1, 5] 5!/2!!
```

> ```
> 1701000
> ```

The general formula returns the same

```
moment2[{7, 6, 5}]
```

> ```
> ... + 1701000 σ[1, 1]^2 σ[1, 2] σ[1, 3]^2 σ[2, 2]^2 σ[2, 3] σ[3, 3] + ...
> ```

If anybody knows this formula please write where it is published!

Comment: After some search: [The moments of the multivariate normal](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FBAZ%2FBAZ32_01%2FS000497270000976Xa.pdf)

Answer (score 17):

If $X = (X_1, ..., X_n)$ denotes a $n$-variate multivariate Normal random variable $N(\mu, \Sigma)$, then the moment generating function is given by:

$$ M(t)=E\left[e^{t'X}\right] = exp\left({t'\mu + \frac12 t' \Sigma t}\right)$$

The mgf can then be used to derive the raw moments you seek. For instance, in say a bivariate setting, the product raw moment $E\left[X_1^r X_2^s\right]$ can be obtained from the mgf $M(t)$ as follows:

$$E\left[X_1^r X_2^s\right] = \frac{\partial ^{r+s}M(t)}{\partial
t_1^r\partial t_2^s}|_{\overset{\rightharpoonup }{t}=\overset{\rightharpoonup }{0}}$$

**Advantages**

This approach has 3 advantages:

FIRST, it is much faster than using Wolfram's in-built `Moment` function.

SECOND, the Isserlis theorem the OP has quoted above requires that the mean vector $\mu$ = 0. By contrast, the mgf approach given here does not require a zero mean vector, and is thus both more general and flexible.

THIRD, comparing to the solution given by @ybeltukov (using Isserlis), the `LeafCount` of the obtained solution is dramatically smaller using our mgf approach ... e.g. 261 using mgf here versus a leaf count of nearly 3 billion for ybeltukov (see the example below).

**Implementation is easy:**

For say a bivariate model:

```
tt = {Subscript[t, 1], Subscript[t, 2]};  
mu = {0, 0}; 
SS = Array[σ, {2, 2}];
```

Then, the mgf is;

```
mgf = Exp[tt.mu + 1/2 tt.SS.tt]
```

Write a little function to extract the raw moments from the mgf:

```
RawMoment[r_, s_] := D[mgf, {Subscript[t,1], r}, {Subscript[t,2], s}] /. Subscript[t,_] -> 0
```

All done.

Example: find $E\left[X_1^{40} X_2^{30}\right]$

Solution:

```
 RawMoment[40, 30];  // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.130264, Null}

compared to:

```
Moment[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, SS], {40, 30}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {1.938334, Null}

... which is about 8 times faster. The output is otherwise the same.

**Comparing to ybeltukov**

In another solution, ybeltukov suggested a function called `moment` (using the OP's Isserlis method). While this is fast, it unfortunately produces ungainly answers. To see this, compare the `LeafCount`:

```
RawMoment[40, 30] // LeafCount
```

> 261

versus

```
moment[{40, 30}] // LeafCount
```

> 2886864330

**For more detail**

For more detail, see, for instance, Chapter 6 of our book, *"Mathematical Statistics with Mathematica"*. A free download of the chapter is now available here:

http://www.mathStatica.com/book/Rose_and_Smith_2002edition_Chapter6.pdf

[ We will be making the entire original first edition of the Springer book available as a free download in the next few days ... ]

Comment: please announce when this is available.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting idea! I add a small update to my answer to decrease the leaf count. I will think, maybe evaluation of derivatives can be accelerated.

Comment: @ybeltukov ---> A small tweak ... but with big benefits! All the solutions now seem to give the same answer (given a zero mean vector) ... ybeltukov is about twice as fast as mgf method here (given zero mean vec). :)

Comment: @wolfies I derive an explicit formula from the moment generation function. If you are interested in it, please see my new answer!

Answer (score 13):

Pairs is unordered and index in each pair is also unordered. Let us choose the order:

1. In each pair the first index is less then the second.
2. Pairs is sorted in ascending order by the first index. If the first indexes is equal then sort by the second.

Examples in the question have the right order.

Let we have powers $(0,\ldots,0,r_i,r_{i+1},\ldots,r_n)$. The first pair is always $\sigma_{i,j}$ where $i$ is the first nonzero power $r_i$. $j\ge i$ can take any index of nonzero powers in the residual list $(0,\ldots,0,r_i-1,r_{i+1},\ldots,r_n)$. So we sort out all the possible first pairs and recursively calculate moment with the residual powers $(0,\ldots,0,r_i-1,r_{i+1},\ldots,r_{j-1},r_j-1,r_{j+1},\ldots,r_n)$

```
ClearAll[moment]
moment[{0 ...}] = 1;
moment[x_List] /; Total[x] == 2 := 
   If[Length[#] == 1, σ[#[[1]], #[[1]]], σ[#[[1]], #[[2]]]] &@
      Position[x, y_?Positive][[All, 1]];
moment[x_List] := moment[x] = Module[{i = LengthWhile[x, # == 0 &] + 1, x2 = x}, x2[[i]]--; 
   Sum[If[x2[[j]] > 0, x2[[j]] σ[i, j] moment@MapAt[# - 1 &, x2, j], 0], 
      {j, i, Length[x]}]];
```

I use [memoization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2639/4678) here because it produces a great speedup.

```
moment[{2, 2}]
```

> ```
> 2 σ[1, 2]^2 + σ[1, 1] σ[2, 2]
> ```

```
m = moment[{400, 0}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.025246

```
md[n_] := MultinormalDistribution[ConstantArray[0, n], 
     Table[σ[Min[i, j], Max[i, j]], {i, n}, {j, n}]];

m == Moment[md[2], {400, 0}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.011387, True}

100x speedup!

```
 d = 2 RandomInteger[5, 5]
```

> {4, 0, 2, 6, 10}

```
 m = moment[d]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.012637

```
 m == Moment[md[5], d] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {3.172868, True}

Even greater speedup!

**Update:** To decrease the leaf count add `//Expand` just after the `MapAt[# - 1 &, x2, j]`. It will be ~2 times slower but still faster then wolfies' `RawMoment`.