# Wick's theorem for Gaussian stochastic variables

Tags: operators

I wonder whether there exists a clever way to implement Wick's theorem for Gaussian stochastic variables $\eta_{j_{i}}$ (with $\langle \eta_{j_{i}}\rangle=0$ for $\forall i$) which in general states:

$$
\begin{align}
\langle \eta_{j_1}\eta_{j_2}\dots\eta_{j_{2n+1}}\rangle&=0\\
\langle \eta_{j_1}\eta_{j_2}\dots\eta_{j_{2n}}\rangle&=\sum_\mathrm{P_d}\sigma_{k_1, k_2}\sigma_{k_3, k_4}\dots\sigma_{2n-1, 2n}\
\end{align}
$$
where one has to sum over only those $(2n)!/(2^n n!)$ permutations $(j_1\dots j_{2n})\Rightarrow (k_1,\dots,k_{2n})$ which lead to different expressions for  $\sigma_{k_1, k_2}\dots\sigma_{k_{2n-1}, k_{2n}}$. And $\sigma_{jk}=\langle \eta_j\eta_k\rangle$ is defined as the covariance matrix.

I think computationally I would prefer a functional form where I define a $\langle \dots\rangle$ operator.

Problems that occur to my mind:

- Need to distinguish between random variables and deterministic variables (the latter ones can be pulled out of the operator).
- How do I cover all the cases at the same time, i.e. four-point correlation functions, six-point correlation functions etc.
- How do I impose the rules to make sure that only permutations which
  lead to different expressions remain?

Maybe anyone of you has already tried to implement this theorem/problem? Any help is highly appreciated as always :)

Comment: I implement Wick's theorem on monomials [in this answer of mine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/170269/34893) (cf. the function `corr`, short for "correlator"). I hope you find it useful.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will take a look at it asap.

Comment: Related question:   https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34779/how-to-efficiently-find-moments-of-a-multinormal-distribution

Answer (score 1):

First define a function that tells you whether a variable is random or not

```
constantQ[x_?NumericQ]:=False
```

And, according to your program you might want to give some up values as follows

```
x1/:constantQ[x1]:=True;
y1/:constantQ[y1]:=False;
(*etc...*)
```

Then define a function `ExpValue` that encloses all your variables. Make it so that variables that evaluate to `True` when `constantQ` is applied are taken out

```
ExpValue[a___,x_?constantQ,b___]:= x ExpValue[a,b];
```

And apply the actual Wick contraction rule when all variables have been taken out

```
ExpValue[a__] /; ! (constantQ /@ And @@ {a}) := Wcontract[{a}];
```

Now the function `Wcontract` can be defined recursively

```
Wcontract[{}]:=1;
Wcontract[a_List] := Sum[sigma[a[[1]], a[[j]]] Wcontract[Delete[a, {{1}, {j}}]], {j, 2, Length[a]}]
```

Where I called `sigma` the two point correlator.