# Obtaining formula of $E[X^T A X B X^T CX]$ for Gaussian $X$

Tags: probability-or-statistics, algebraic-manipulation

Suppose $X$ is an $m\times n$ random matrix where rows are I.I.D. samples $x$ of $n$-dimensional Gaussian. The code at the end of the post verifies a candidate (incorrect) formula for the following expression in terms of $H=E[xx']$ (this parameterization simplified [related formula](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/589669/gaussian-fourth-moment-formulas) considerably compared to $\mu,\Sigma$ parameterization). What's the correct formula?

$$E[X^T A X B X^T CX]\approx m(m-1)HBH$$

There's this detailed [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34779/how-to-efficiently-find-moments-of-a-multinormal-distribution) on computing arbitrary moments of Gaussian distributions.

Alternatively there's this [notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/wicks-cumulants.nb) which automatically derives non-central Wick's Theorem in summation form by doing the following:

1. `MomentConvert[Moment[{1, 1, 1, 1}], "Cumulant"]`
2. Set cumulants of order 3 and 4 to zero
3. `MomentConvert` back

[image]

A similar approach may be feasible for the question at hand, but a bit of a programming challenge!

```
d = 3;
x1 = Array[xx1, d];
x2 = Array[xx2, d];
X = {x1, x2};

SeedRandom[1];
sigma = DiagonalMatrix[RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {d}]];
mu = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {d}];
mu = ConstantArray[0, {d}];


H = sigma + Outer[Times, mu, mu];
dist = MultinormalDistribution[mu, sigma];
EX[expr_] := 
  Expectation[
   expr, {x1 \[Distributed] dist, x2 \[Distributed] dist}];
m = Length[X];
Unprotect[C];
{A, C} = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {2, m, m}];
B = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {d, d}];

Print["Check passed: ", 
 EX[X\[Transpose] . A . X . B . X\[Transpose] . C . X] == 
  m (m - 1) H . B . H]
```

Related unanswered [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/589849/value-of-ext-a-x-b-xt-cx-for-gaussian-matrices-x) on stats.SE

Comment: I wonder if first solving for $E[X^T A X B X^T X]$ and $E[X^T X B X^T CX]$ would help lead one to a general formula for $E[X^T A X B X^T CX]$.

Comment: Your question involves a multivariate normal with a diagonal covariance matrix (rather than the general covariance matrix in the link you presented) and so using `Moment` is pretty fast for your example.

Comment: Some speculation:  If $X^T.A.X.B.X^T.C.X==X^T.C.X.B.X^T.A.X$, then one could target solving $X^T.D.X.B.X^T.D.X$ as $X^T.A.X.B.X^T.C.X = (X^T.(A+C).X.B.X^T.(A+C).X - X^T.A.X.B.X^T.A.X - X^T.C.X.B.X^T.C.X)/2$.

Answer (score 7):

*Note: Many thanks to @JimB for pointing out a mistake in an earlier version.*

This question can be worked out by pencil and paper.

**Special case.** Let me first assume that $Y$ is a rectangular matrix whose entries are i.i.d. and standard normal, $N(0,1)$. Then:
$$
E[Y^TAYBY^TCY]
=
(\text{tr}  A)(\text{tr}  C) B + B^T \text{tr} (A^T C) + \text{tr} (B) \text{tr} (AC) \mathbb{1}
$$
The proof goes like this:
$$
E[Y^TAYBY^TCY]_{ij}
= \sum_{a,b,c,d,e,f} E[Y_{ai} A_{ab} Y_{bc} B_{cd} Y_{ed} C_{ef} Y_{fj}]
= \sum_{a,b,c,d,e,f} A_{ab} B_{cd} C_{ef} E[Y_{ai} Y_{bc} Y_{ed} Y_{fj}]
$$
Using [Isserli's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem) this is equal to
$$
= \sum_{a,b,c,d,e,f} A_{ab} B_{cd} C_{ef}
(\delta_{ab} \delta_{ic} \delta_{ef} \delta_{dj} + \delta_{ae} \delta_{id} \delta_{bf} \delta_{cj}
+ \delta_{af} \delta_{ij} \delta_{be} \delta_{cd})
$$
where $\delta$ is the Kronecker symbol. It is now just a matter of checking what is contracted with what, for example in the first term we have $A_{ab} \delta_{ab}$ which gives $\text{tr}  A$, and so on. The result follows.

By a similar calculation:
$$
E[YAY] = E[Y^T A Y^T] = A^T
\qquad
E[YAY^T] = E[Y^T AY] = \text{tr}(A) \mathbb{1}
$$

**General case (but still zero mean).** Now assume that $Z = YK$ where $K$ is some constant matrix, and denote $H = K^T K$. Then
$$
E[Z^TAZBZ^TCZ]
=
(\text{tr}  A)(\text{tr}  C) HBH + HB^T H \text{tr} (A^T C) + \text{tr} (BH) \text{tr} (AC) H
$$

The proof is, using the special case above:
$$
E[Z^TAZBZ^TCZ]
=
E[K^TY^TAYKBK^T K^T Y^TCYK]
=
K^T E[Y^TAY(KBK^T) Y^TCY]K
=
(\text{tr}  A)(\text{tr}  C) K^TKBK^TK + K^T KB^T K^TK \text{tr} (A^T C) + \text{tr} (KBK^T) \text{tr} (AC) K^T K
$$
and then replacing $K^T K = H$.

By a similar calculation:
$$
E[ZAZ] = A^T H
\qquad
E[Z^T A Z^T] = H A^T$$
$$
E[ZAZ^T] = \text{tr}(AH) \mathbb{1}
\qquad
E[Z^T AZ] = \text{tr}(A) H
$$

**General case (non-zero mean).** Suppose $M$ is the mean, $E[X] = M$. This is equivalent to $X = Z + M$ where $Z$ is as before.
Then
$$
E[X^TAXBX^TCX]\\
=
(\text{tr}  A)(\text{tr}  C) HBH + HB^T H \text{tr} (A^T C) + \text{tr} (BH) \text{tr} (AC) H\\
+ \text{tr}(A) HBM^TCM\\
+ H (AMB)^T CM\\
+ \text{tr}(BH) M^TACM\\
+ \text{tr}(AMBM^TC) H \\
+ M^TA (BM^TC)^T H\\
+ \text{tr}(C) M^TAMB H \\
+ M^TAMBM^TCM
$$

The proof goes like this (expectation values of terms that are linear or cubic in $Z$ are  equal to zero):
$$
E[X^TAXBX^TCX]\\
=
E[Z^TAZBZ^TCZ]\\
+ E[Z^TAZBM^TCM]\\
+ E[Z^TAMBZ^TCM]\\
+ E[M^TAZBZ^TCM]\\
+ E[Z^TAMBM^TCZ]\\
+ E[M^TAZBM^TCZ]\\
+ E[M^TAMBZ^TCZ]\\
+ E[M^TAMBM^TCM]\\
=
E[Z^TAZBZ^TCZ]\\
+ E[Z^TAZ]BM^TCM\\
+ E[Z^T(AMB)Z^T]CM\\
+ M^TAE[ZBZ^T]CM\\
+ E[Z^T(AMBM^TC)Z]\\
+ M^TAE[Z(BM^TC)Z]\\
+ M^TAMBE[Z^TCZ]\\
+ M^TAMBM^TCM
$$
Now it is just a matter of plugging in the results given for $Z$.

**Note.** It would be easy to make a mistake in such a calculation, so use at your own risk :)

Comment: Does your formula work? Isserlis theorem is for centered variables. I haven't seen the non-centered version, this is why I used `MomentConvert` in the notebook linked

Comment: edited the question to clarify that I'm looking for generic version, not necessarily centered

Comment: +1 Excellent!  I think you have a typo in $E[Z^TAZBZ^TCZ]=(\text{tr}  A)(\text{tr}  C) HBH + HB^T H \text{tr} (A^T C) + \text{tr} (BH) \text{tr} (A^TC) H$ in the the last $\text{tr} (A^TC)$ should be $\text{tr} (A C)$ (i.e., no transpose for $A$).  The *Mathematica* code would be `Tr[A] Tr[CC] H . B . H + H . Transpose[B] . H Tr[Transpose[A] . CC] + Tr[B . H] Tr[A . CC] H` (where I've used `CC` instead of `C` because the symbol `C` is reserved).

Comment: Two items:  (1) This matrix solution is tens (or hundreds) of thousands times faster than brute force approach using replacement rules, and (2) you should post (or would it be cross-post?) your answer for Yaroslav's bounty on CrossValidated.

Comment: Thanks @JimB, I edited. I think I will stick to this friendly SE for the time being :)

Comment: If you added in the associated *Mathematica* code, I would think you'd be relatively certain to obtain the bounty.

Answer (score 3):

This is just an extended comment in that one can find the expectation much quicker by using replacement rules rather than using `Expectation`.  (I understand that the real answer must be in matrix terms.)

```
d = 3; (* Dimensions *)
m = 2; (* Number of independent samples *)
X = Table[x[i, j], {i, m}, {j, d}];

H = DiagonalMatrix[Range[d]];  (* Covariance matrix *)
dist = MultinormalDistribution[H];

A = Array[a, {d, d}];
W = X\[Transpose] . X . A . X\[Transpose] . X;
expectations = {x[i_, j_]^3 -> 0, x[i_, j_]^4 -> 3 j^2, x[i_, j_]^2 x[i_, k_]^2 -> j k, 
  x[i_, j_]^2 -> j, x[i_, j_] -> 0};
AbsoluteTiming[(X\[Transpose] . X . A . X\[Transpose] . X // Expand) /. expectations;]
(* {0.0028874, Null} *)
```

It takes 1.4 seconds using `Expectation` with your code.

The expectations in the replacement list are found using `Moments` and recognizing that each random term (after `Expand`) is a product of powers of 1, 2, or 3 elements of the $X$ matrix such as $x_{1,1}^2 x_{1,3}^2 and $x_{2,1} x_{2,3}^3.  And the expectation of any of those products with any term with an odd power is zero.

So with $d=3$ we have the expectation of $x_{1,1}^2 x_{1,3}^2$ being

```
Moment[dist, {2, 0, 2}]
(* 3 *)
```

For $x_{2,2}^4$ the expectation is

```
Moment[dist, {0, 4, 0}]
(* 12 *)
```

And the replacement list was constructed by noticing patterns.  (Unfortunately the order of the replacements is important as I need to replace `x[i, j]^2` before replacing `x[i, j]` with zero.)

Comment: The "how to get matrix form of moment" seems similar to "how to get matrix form of derivative". Here Sjoerd [does this](https://github.com/ssmit1986/DualNumbers/issues/1#issuecomment-692957535) using replacement rules