# Integration of Booles and Gaussians in high dimensions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics, symbolic

### Context

As a follow up of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9928/1089),  I would like to 
predict the connectivity of the so-called cosmic web in arbitrary dimensions.

The connectivity $\kappa$ is defined as the number of ridges connecting a given maxima  to its surrounding saddles, which in turn therefore corresponds to 
$2 n_{\rm max}/ n_{\rm saddle}$ where $n_{\rm max}$ and  $n_{\rm saddle}$ are 
the total number of maxima and saddles in the field.

This is how the cosmic web looks like in 3D:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

so the motivation is to predict how many filaments are connected to a given node
from first principes.

### Attempt

As a starting point I am restricting myself to
 a [Gaussian random field](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9951/1089).
For such fields it can be shown that the following code computes this ratio for an arbitrary dimension $d$.

```
d=3; 
var = Table[ToExpression["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, d}];
mat = ConstantArray[1/(d (d + 2)) , {d, d}];
Do[mat[[i, i]] = 3/(d (d + 2)), {i, d}]; 
arg = Abs[Times @@ var] Abs[
    Product[var[[i]] - var[[j]], {i, d}, {j, i - 1}]];
pdf = MultinormalDistribution[Table[0, {Length[mat]}], mat];
fun1 = Function[var // Evaluate, 
   Times @@ (Boole[# < 0] & /@ var) arg // Evaluate];
fun2 = Function[var // Evaluate, 
   Boole[Last[var] > 0] Times @@ (Most@(Boole[# < 0] & /@ var)) arg //
     Evaluate];

2   Integrate[fun2 @@ var PDF[pdf, var],
   Sequence @@ Map[{#, -Infinity, Infinity} &, var]]/
  Integrate[fun1 @@ var PDF[pdf, var],
   Sequence @@ Map[{#, -Infinity, Infinity} &, var]]
```

For instance it returns `4` for $d=2$ and

2 (18 Sqrt[2] + 29 Sqrt[3]) /
    (-18 Sqrt[2] + 29 Sqrt[3]) = 6.11

for $d=3$. It is strikingly close to a cubic face centred lattice, but with some level of impurity to the crystal.

for $d>3$ I have resorted to `NIntegrate`

```
2 d  NIntegrate[fun2 @@ var PDF[pdf, var] // Evaluate,
   Sequence @@ Map[{#, -Infinity, -1, 0, 1, Infinity} &, var] // 
    Evaluate, PrecisionGoal -> 20, MinRecursion -> 8]/
  NIntegrate[fun1 @@ var PDF[pdf, var] // Evaluate,
   Sequence @@ Map[{#, -Infinity, -1, 0, 1, Infinity} &, var] // 
    Evaluate,
   PrecisionGoal -> 20, MinRecursion -> 8]
```

and I find   8.35 10.75 13.23 for $d$=4,5,6

### Question

> Is is possible to compute the ratio analytically for $d>3$?

FYI, for $d=4$ the integrant of the numerator looks like this

```
      int = fun2 @@ var PDF[pdf, var]; int
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Alternative Question

> What options should one use with `NIntegrate` so that the code works for $d>6$.

Scientifically, it would be of interest to go up to d=11 in the context 
of so-called landscape inflation.

As a test, I have tried the following brute force Monte Carlo:

```
 d=5;
 dat2 = ParallelTable[dat = RandomVariate[pdf, 150000];
 {2 d (fun2 @@ # & /@ dat // Total), (fun1 @@ # & /@ dat // 
   Total)}, {25}]; // AbsoluteTiming
 Mean@ dat2 // First[#]/Last[#] &
```

which is embarrassingly parallel but not very accurate.

So far I have

$\kappa^d$ = $4$, $6.11$, $8.35$, $10.73$, $13.23$, $15.85$
for $d=$      $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$, $7$ resp.

From inspection of $d\le 7$ we conjecture that it is closely approximated 
by

$$
 \kappa^d= 2d+\left(\frac{2d-4}{7}\right)^{7/4}.
 $$

PS: I have now also [asked this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2791208/32833) on math.stackexchange

Comment: You could try to execute `NIntegrate` with a high precision, and use `RootApproximant` and cross your fingers. With a bit of luck, the analytic result is algebraic and `RootApproximant` will be able to reconstruct it from its approximate numerical value.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=RootApproximant%5BN%5B(18+Sqrt%5B2%5D+%2B+29+Sqrt%5B3%5D)+%2F+(-18+Sqrt%5B2%5D+%2B+29+Sqrt%5B3%5D),20%5D%5D In this case, `RootApproximant` was able to recover the correct expression. If you reduce the precision (say, from `20` to `5`), it fails. So you'll need several correct decimal places to get the correct result.

Comment: Trying the case `d=3` I find that `Expectation[fun2 @@ var, var \[Distributed] pdf]` is faster than `Integrate`, by roughly 30%. Didn't have time to test it for larger `d` though. Related: [How to deal with complicated Gaussian integrals in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6845/245)

Comment: Isn't expectation using integrate?

Comment: I think it uses `Integrate` with additional assumptions, but also could choose different methods such as FT of characteristic function. Not sure what it does under the hood in this case - and the speedup isn't enough to make larger `d` really feasible anyway...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Some partial results.

So I've been working on this problem in my spare time, and I wanted to post some partial results I got should it help someone else (and, of course, OP) to work through the problem.

First of all, a more-or-less compact expression for the integral OP is after:

```
-2 d Integrate[
 Times @@ Array[λ, d] Abs[Product[λ[j] - λ[i], {i, 1, d}, {j, i + 1, d}]] Exp[-1/2 Sum[λ[i] λ[j] (-d/2), {i, 1, d}, {j, 1, d}] - 1/2 Sum[λ[i]^2 1/2 d (2 + d), {i, 1, d}]]
     , Evaluate[Sequence @@ Table[{λ[i], -∞, 0}, {i, 1, d - 1}]], {λ[d], 0, ∞}]/
Integrate[
 Times @@ Array[λ, d] Abs[Product[λ[j] - λ[i], {i, 1, d}, {j, i + 1, d}]] Exp[-1/2 Sum[λ[i] λ[j] (-d/2), {i, 1, d}, {j, 1, d}] - 1/2 Sum[λ[i]^2 1/2 d (2 + d), {i, 1, d}]]
     , Evaluate[Sequence @@ Table[{λ[i], -∞, 0}, {i, 1, d}]]]
```

Integrating numerically using the options `Method -> "GaussKronrodRule", PrecisionGoal -> 20, AccuracyGoal -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 30, MaxRecursion -> 50`, I found
$$
\kappa^{(4)}=\color{red}{8.34922775472958914088481}88794
$$
of which I am pretty sure the red figures are significative. Perhaps a few more figures are as well.

It would be great to evaluate this integral to a better precision, and use `RootApproximant` to guess the analytic result. If, as in the $d=2,3$ cases, the result is algebraic, `RootApproximant` will be able to reconstruct it from the numerical value if given enough correct digits. My attempts at doing this appear to have failed, so my guess is that $\kappa^{(d)}$ is not algebraic for $d\ge4$. Oh well.

If it turns out that the analytic form of $\kappa^{(4)}$ can be obtained, and so can the next few values, perhaps `FindSequenceFunction` will be able to guess the value of $\kappa^{(d)}$ for arbitrary $d$. Wouldn't it be nice?

A possible approach to improve the convergence is to enforce some change of variables. For now, I managed to prove that the change of variables $\vec\lambda\to A\vec\lambda$ diagonalises the exponent, where $A$ is the (orthogonal) matrix given by

```
A = Join[Table[PadRight[Join[ConstantArray[-(1/Sqrt[j (1 + j)]), j], {Sqrt[j/(1 + j)]}], d], {j, 1, d - 1}], {ConstantArray[1/Sqrt[d], d]}];
```

In particular, the inverse of the matrix $M$ in the OP satisfies

```
ConstantArray[-d/2, {d, d}] + 1/2 d (2 + d) IdentityMatrix[d] == Transpose[A].DiagonalMatrix[Join[ConstantArray[1/2 d (2 + d), d - 1], {d}]].A
```

so that the eigenvalues are $d-1$ copies of `1/2 d (2 + d)`, and one copy of `d`.

My hope is that this basis allows us to factorise the integral and evaluate it analytically for arbitrary $d$. I haven't had the time to explore this yet.

Finally, let me mention that I also evaluated $\kappa^{(d)}$ numerically using the options `Method -> "MonteCarlo"` (with increasing number of points to estimate the error), and I found
$$
\begin{aligned}
\kappa^{(8)}&=18.7(1)\\
\kappa^{(9)}&=21.4(2)\\
\kappa^{(10)}&=24.4(2)\\
\kappa^{(11)}&=27.4(2)
\end{aligned}
$$

The evaluation of $\kappa^{(d)}$ for higher $d$ is straightforward: just use the integral expression I wrote above, but change `Integrate` to `NIntegrate` and use the option `Method -> "MonteCarlo"`. You will need to increase the number of points though: for $d=11$ I had to use `MaxPoints -> 700000000`. For higher $d$, you'll probably need to use some more. And to estimate the error, you can evaluate `NIntegrate` a few times, and take the mean and standard deviation. At this point, the evaluation of $\kappa^{(d)}$ is just a matter of patience. I guess at some point it will be necessary to increase the working precision too. I leave this to you, if you feel more values of $\kappa^{(d)}$ are necessary.

Finally, let me mention that the results so far are all in fact consistent with OP's conjecture:

```
Show[
     ListPlot[Transpose[{Range[2, 11], {4, 6.11, 8.35, 10.73, 13.23, 15.85, 18.7, 21.4, 24.4, 27.4}}]],
     Plot[{2 d, 2 d + ((7 d - 14)/25)^(7/4)}, {d, 2, 11}]
]
```

[image]

I'll update this post as I get more results.

Comment: @chris Thank you for asking, but there's no need to. I'm glad I could help :-)

Comment: Ok: we ll add something like We thanks the community of \href{http://mathematica.stackexchange.com}{mathematica.stackexchange} for help. Next paper should be about explaining why this conjecture holds :-) Could you please post explicitly your code for the MC method?

Answer (score 2):

Through some indirect theoretical consideration it turns out it can be shown that the connectivity for $d=4$ is in fact symbolic and  equal to

```
 -((200 \[Pi])/(114-75 \[Pi]+100 cot^-1(2))) = 8.3492277547295891408846033687519774106386215942178
```

So I can confirm that @accidentalFourierTransform's result is correct up to 22 digits :-)

The sketch of the proof is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3234039/32833)

Comment: Very cool :D ${}$