# Expectation and direct integration give different results

Tags: symbolic, stochastic-calculus

I have an integral I want to compute:

$\qquad \int_{\mathbb R^4} e^{-(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)} \left( 1-x_1-x_3 \right) dx$

To me, this should be equivalent (modulo some scaling factor) to computing the expectation of $(1-x_1^2-x_3^2+ 0 x_2 + 0 x_4)$ when $x$ is a zero-mean Gaussian variable with variance $2I_4$. See [How to deal with complicated Gaussian integrals in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6845/how-to-deal-with-complicated-gaussian-integrals-in-mathematica)).

So I tried

```
Sqrt[(2 Pi)^4] Sqrt[2^4] 
  Expectation[
    (1 - x1^2 - x3^2), 
    {x1, x2, x3, x4} \[Distributed] MultinormalDistribution[2 IdentityMatrix[4]]]
```

which gives $-48 \pi^2$. However, when I compute

```
Integrate[Exp[-x1^2 - x2^2 - x3^2 - x4^2] (1 - x1^2 - x3^2), 
  {x1, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x2,-Infinity,Infinity}, 
  {x3, -Infinity,Infinity}, {x4, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

The result is $0$.

I am not sure what is going on here. Which one is correct?.

Comment: I think the variance should be `1/2 IdentityMatrix[4]`.

Comment: True, which actually gives 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only consider the part `x1,x3` of your integral
`Integrate[
 Exp[-x1^2 - x3^2 ] (1 - x1^2 - x3^2), {x1, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}, {x3, -Infinity, Infinity} ]` it`s possible to transform in polarcoordinates (pointsymmetrical integrand!) which gives

```
Integrate[Exp[-r^2] (1 -r^2) 2Pi r, {r, -Infinity,Infinity}  ] 
(*0*)
```

That means your `Integrate`-result is ok!